# How to Get array values after a specific text

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have an array which is made from the following string..

```
FixedLines Rs. 0.200 / 1 min Rs. 0.600 / 1 min
```

I converted this string into string array by splitting based on the spaces in the string.
Now i am trying to get the string after substring `Rs.` means i want the values `0.200 / 1 min` and `0.600 / 1 min`.

Please help me how can i get these values from the string array into string.

Comment: _"how can i get these values from the string array into string"_ it's not clear what you actually want.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `FixedLines Rs. 0.200 / 1 min Rs. 0.600 / 1 min` This is my string array formed by splitting string based on spaces.Now i want to get Values after `Rs.` .How to get it?

Comment: Is it enough to split on `" Rs. "` and then taking the last two entries?

Comment: @Sayse Yes its enough but how ?

Comment: You said you were already splitting?.. just change what you are splitting on with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could  split by `Rs.` and take only the parts which contain `/`:

```
string str = "FixedLines Rs. 0.200 / 1 min Rs. 0.600 / 1 min";
var parts = str.Split(new[] { " Rs. " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(p => p.Contains("/"));

foreach(string part in parts)
    Console.WriteLine(part);
```

Outputs:

```
0.200 / 1 min
0.600 / 1 min
```

You:

> How to get these two values into string?

You can use `string.Join`, f.e. if you want to separate them with new-line characters:

```
string values = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, parts);
```

You:

> I am sorry ! but i want into two string for example str1 and str2

I suggest to use a collection instead of single variables or are you sure that there are always only two values?

You can use `ToArray` or `ToList` to create a collection, then you can use the indexer or LINQ extension method like `First`,`Last` or `ElementAtOrDefault`:

```
string[] values = parts.ToArray();
string firstVal = values.First();
string lastVal = values.Last();
```

Comment: Working !.One small query ..How to get these two values into string

Comment: @user3924730: how do you want to merge these two entries into a single string? You can use `String.Join`, for example if you want to concat them with `Environment.NewLine`: `string result=string.Join(Environment.NewLine,parts);`.

Comment: I dont want to merge i want these values into individual string only..How to get into from foreach ..

Comment: @user3924730: i have explained it already in my last comment  and in my answer. Use `String.Join`. You can replace `Environment.NewLine` with whatever you want, even with `""` if you want to stick them together.

Comment: I am sorry ! but i want into two string for example `str1` and `str2`

Comment: @user3924730 - You already have the two strings in `parts` with this, you can either just access them individually via their index e.g `parts[0]` or just loop through as shown

Answer (score 1):

You can do what Sayse said in the comments to your question.

```
        string phrase = "FixedLines Rs. 0.200 / 1 min Rs. 0.600 / 1 min";

        var split = new string[1];
        split[0] = "Rs.";

        var results = phrase.Split(split, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could just do

```
 stringName.Split(new string[]{" Rs. "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Skip(1);
```

Split the string based on `Rs.` and then skip the first entry